# Grab a screenshot of Chrome using Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: java, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to grab a screenshot of an open window using the Chrome Development Tools remote debugger?

For example, I'm connecting to the remote debug port and I have this
code which pops an empty window:

```
   private void sendWindowPop(int width, int height) throws
IOException {
       hsc.send("{\"method\": \"Runtime.evaluate\", \"id\": "
               + hsc.nextInt()
               + ", \"params\": {"
               + "\"expression\":
\"window.open('about:blank','name','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,"
               + "location=0,status=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width="
               + width
               + ",height="
               + height
               + "');\""
               + "}}");
```

(hsc is my connection to the debugger at http://localhost:9222)

Then, I load up my target URL with this:

```
    private void loadPage(String uriString) throws IOException {
       hsc.send("{\"method\": \"Page.open\", \"id\": " +
       hsc.nextInt() + ", \"params\": {\"url\": \"" + uriString + "\"}}");
       hsc.waitFor(ChromeNotifications.PAGE_LOADEVENTFIRED, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
   }
```

The code above works fine, and first pops a window and then loads the
URL.  Ideally, the next thing I would like to do is grab a screenshot
of the loaded web page.  Right now, these browser windows pop into an
Xvfb virtual desktop, and I can use ImageMagick's import tool to grab
a screenshot of the target window, but *only if it's in the
foreground*.

This is a problem, since this application is designed to run in
parallel with multiple windows popping into the virtual desktop.  Any
window overlapping my target window will just give me a black
screenshot, since Xfvb only renders what's visible.

I also looked into the API reference, chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab.  No luck there, it doesn't capture what's not visible.

Is there a way, using the remote debugger, to grab a screenshot of an
open window?

(for reference purposes, my ImageMagick command for import is this)

```
    DISPLAY=:0.0 import -window "Google - Chromium" screenshot.png
```

Where I open the URL http://www.google.com in my chromium browser using loadPage() above.  It works great as long as the "Google - Chromium" window that pops is unobstructed and has focus.  Drop another window over part of it, and I get a big black area that was not rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome Remote Debugging Protocol now supports the **Page.captureScreenshot** function

Here is an example in coffee-script

```
screenshot: (name, callback)=>
    safeName = name.replace(/[^()^a-z0-9._-]/gi, '_') + ".png"
    png_File = "./_screenshots".append_To_Process_Cwd_Path().folder_Create()
                               .path_Combine(safeName)

    @chrome._chrome.Page.captureScreenshot (err, image)->
      require('fs').writeFile png_File, image.data, 'base64',(err)->
         callback()
```

(snippet from
https://github.com/TeamMentor/TM_4_0_Design/blob/Issue_80_Jade_Cleanup/QA/API/QA-TM_4_0_Design.coffee#L54)

Comment: The link is dead :( How do you access / create the `Page` object?

Comment: Hi, it looks like that branch is not there anymore

take a look at 

https://github.com/TeamMentor/TM_4_0_Design/blob/94612a699aa03565bea6c045400bccd1cc68dd76/QA/API/QA-TM_4_0_Design.coffee#L56

and

https://github.com/TeamMentor/TM_4_0_Design/blob/94612a699aa03565bea6c045400bccd1cc68dd76/QA/tests/help-pages.coffee#L40

Comment: Is there something usable here for someone that just wants to paste a command in the console pane, or press a hotkey?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Aviary Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ncgcgghbabbopfcpgcjpfffdgnbadegf)

Check this site too:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2011/08/25-must-have-chrome-extensions-for-web-designers-and-developers/

Comment: Hi Adel, I looked into Aviary and it has some interesting options and a public API, but the API is geared toward image editing.  I didn't see anything that lets me take a screenshot programmatically, so my search continues.  Thanks!

Comment: @torgis I hope you found what you were looking for!

Comment: I found some interesting things but nothing did exactly what I was looking for.  Instead, I'm in the process of writing my own.  Wish me luck!  :)

Comment: @torgis If you need help, you can always come back here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need Java based solution use [cdp4j](https://github.com/webfolderio/cdp4j) to capture **full page** screen.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    SessionFactory factory = new Launcher().launch();

    Path file = createTempFile("screenshot", ".png");

    try (Session session = factory.create()) {
        session.navigate("https://webfolder.io");
        session.waitDocumentReady();
        byte[] data = session.captureScreenshot();
        write(file, data);
    }

    if (isDesktopSupported()) {
        getDesktop().open(file.toFile());
    }

    factory.close();
}
```

[Screenshot.java](https://github.com/webfolderio/cdp4j/blob/master/src/test/java/io/webfolder/cdp/sample/Screenshot.java)